# Booting PPC Mac from CD using Open Firmware

Tags: mac, cd, ppc

I've not had any success booting from a CD or DVD with various PPC versions of Ubuntu using any of the suggested keys such as "C". The only thing that has worked consistently for me is booting into open firmware. The problem I am now running into is that when I tell OF to boot from the CD it can't find the \install\yaboot file. I think this is because the CD is burned with an iso disk image. How do I either (a) reference the disk image in the CD boot command (e.g., boot cd:,\install\yaboot doesn't work) or (b) burn a non-iso CD?

Right now I'm working with the 10.04 Desktop distro.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the PRAM/PRU as per the powerpc faq? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ

Answer (score 1):

Just press the alt-key while booting with the CD inserted. After some time you will get an icon for every bootable device on your system.

Select the penguin-icon an press the right arrow below. This will start Ubuntu from the ISO-CD.

However as of today you can save your time downloading Ubuntu 12.04 live-CD for PPC G5-Macs as the offered ISO-CD is showing a blank icon bar with a pink and empty desktop superimposing the 'normal' Ubuntu-Desktop seen on Linux. Only the upper menu bar is showing up.

I don't understand why this hasn't been tested as there are hundred thousands of PPC-Macs out there, which have been obsoleted because of an Apple infight with PPC-Manufacturers. And I am not the only one who wants to keep the Hardware as long as possible. Apple is still updating Safari and iTunes for these systems. Obsoleting 64bit  2GHZ ++ multiprocessor hardware but trying to still make a buck with us is an argument to turn my back to Apple. And I think there are thousands of other PPC users out there. However Canonical seems not to be interested in those potential users either.